# I have a supposedly remains of a windows update sitting on my data drive. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

So I recently discovered that there was a folder with a 32-character name (hashed?) sitting in my data drive. Its contents appear to resemble some kind of old windows update. I can't be certain, since whenever I try to open one of the subfolders it contains I get an access denied error (only SYSTEM is allowed in).

This folder is a thorn in my eye. I don't have access to it, and I do not have access to the group policy manager.

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that they're old updates, though I've usually had that problem with 3rd party updaters (e.g. Dell). The way to solve it is to give yourself ownership of the file (which as the computer administrator you'd think you'd have but....Windows, 'nuff said), after which you should be able to delete it. [This walkthrough](http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm) will get you there, I think.

Comment: thanks.. I can now access the folders. Though it claims I require permission from myself (?) to actually delete the folders. Side note: apparently it are the remains of a visual studio update.

Comment: I had to fiddle with some permissions, but this was the basic step. Thanks for the help :)